# MySQL Invalid DateTime Format Only For Specific Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a PHP scrip (Laravel Artisan Command) which iterates through the whole Bitcoin blockchain and stores transactions that match a certain criteria into a MySQL database. This has been working fine for over a week (running 24/7), but today it threw an error and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.
For every transaction I store different information about it (like information about the block it was included in, it's ID, etc.) including a `created_at` timestamp. I use `Carbon` (`Carbon::createFromTimeStampUTC($timestamp)`) to correctly format the timestamp (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) and as I said before this has worked just fine.
I just checked the progress a couple of minutes ago and I was greeted with the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2016-03-13 02:04:44' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

If I try to insert this value manually into the table it rounds the time up to `03:00:00` for some reason. I don't see a reason why this would be an invalid format as the error states since it worked flawlessly for `554792` transactions so far.

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks perfect to me. Was this an isolated error, or is it happening regularly now?

Comment: could this be related to your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809973/mysql-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value-when-creating-some

Comment: In the US, the time change was on March 13th, 2016, so it's most likely it.

Comment: This may offer a solution to your problem http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-time-zones-in-mysql

Comment: @CarlosRoque Thanks, definitely seems like a plausible solution! Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it as the best solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was noted that the OPs question might have been related to DST problems. This is best described in this question 
[Mysql Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value when creating some dummy data for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809973/mysql-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value-when-creating-some)

It seems this article might have a possible solution to the problem

http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-time-zones-in-mysql

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone in the future that might have the same problem here's what I did to solve this. Since I was retrieving the data from Bitcoin I was sure the data was correct (i.e. the date `2016-03-13 02:04:44`) and that there was a problem with my MySQL setup. It turns out my MySQL server was using the system timezone which was `Eastern Time`, but the data from the Bitcoin Client was in `UTC`. So all I did was change the MySQL server timezone (`SET GLOBAL time_zone='+00:00';`) and now everything works just fine.

Comment: I wonder if in MySql, the Easter Time zone accounts for DST while UTC 00:00 knows there is no DST